# Fatal Error in JModuleHelper

Tags: module, templates, template-override, fatal-error

I am using a custom template, and when I enable a certain module, I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in 
/home/my_host_username/public_html/libraries/cms/module/helper.php on line 202
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is one funny problem.
It seems that Joomla includes code from **module template overrides** in a manner that **certain variable names do affect the core JModuleHelper renderModule function**.

All you need to do to reproduce this bug-like behavior, is to write the following line in your module template override:

```
$template = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true);
```

By loading any object in a variable called `$template`, you break your site.

So, the problem has a simple solution. Namely:
Search the module template override code (inside `templates/your_template/html/mod_modulename`)
or possibly even in the module itself (inside `modules/mod_modulename`), for `$template` and replace with anything else, like `$a_template` or `$my_template` and this will be fixed.

Make sure to let the developer know, if this is not something written by you.